# How to stub aws-sdk

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon, aws-sdk

Lets say I have the following

```
// file sample.js
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var dynamoDB = new aws.DynamoDB();

exports.processData = function(){
  var data = dynamoDB.getItem(params);
  // so something with data
};
```

How can I write unit tests for the above code sample.

```
//file sample_test.js
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var sinon = require('sinon');

// the following code doesnt seem to stub the function
// the actual function is still used in sample.js
var getItemStub = sinon.stub();
aws.DynamoDB.prototype.getItem = getItemStub;

var sample = require('./sample');
```

What will be a good way to stub the aws-sdk api. I was thinking of using [SinonJS](http://sinonjs.org/) to achieve it, but I am open to other libraries and suggestions .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MY current solution is to expose a function in sample.js like shown below.

```
function overRide(data) {
  dynamoDB = data.dynamoDB;
}

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
  exports.overRide = overRide;
}
```

Now in my test case I can do the following which will stub the aws api.

```
//file sample_test.js
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var sinon = require('sinon');
var sample = require('./sample');

var ddb = new aws.DynamoDB();
ddb.getItem = sinon.stub();

sample.overRideAWS({dynamoDB: ddb});
```

Answer (score 6):

We have created an [aws-sdk-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk-mock) npm module which mocks out all the AWS SDK services and methods.  https://github.com/dwyl/aws-sdk-mock

It's really easy to use. Just call AWS.mock with the service, method and a stub function.

```
AWS.mock('DynamoDB', 'getItem', function(params, callback) {
    callback(null, 'success');
});
```

Then restore the methods after your tests by calling:

```
AWS.restore('DynamoDB', 'getItem');
```

Or to restore them all call:

```
AWS.restore();
```

Comment: I don't see way to specify different responses based on the arguments passed. Is this possible?

Comment: You get the params, so look at those to determine what you want to send in the callback. The body of that function doesn't have to be a simple callback(null, 'success');